# Reshaping nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the feeling this is a very basic question, but I can't seem to find the way to solve this easily.

I have imported a set of data from a txt file into a table so the resulting list has the following structure:

```
{{x1,y1,f1},{x2,y2,f2},...}
```

I want it to reshape it into this form:

```
{{{x1,y1},f1},{{x2,y2},f2},...}
```

I apologize because I know it must be trivial but I haven't found the way yet. I've always had problems manipulating lists in Mathematica so, if anyone has any resource I can use to learn about this it'd be very much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Look at the output for `Apply[{{#1, #2}, #3} &, {a, b, c}]` and it should help you.  Check [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) for more details.

Comment: Also possible is the following: `reshape = Curry[Replace, {3, 1, 2}][{s_, t_, u_} :> {{s, t}, u}, {1}]`. Then `{{x1, y1, f1}, {x2, y2, f2}} // reshape` gives the desired result.

Comment: @JasonB. this should be `Apply[{{#1, #2}, #3} &, {{x1, y1, f1}, {x2, y2, f2}}, {1}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think my vote is this so far, but I bet there's even cleaner/more clever ways to do this:

```
data = {{x1, y1, f1}, {x2, y2, f2}}
Replace[data, {x_, y_, f_} :> {{x, y}, f}, {1}]
```

I like the Apply solution just fine too:

```
Apply[{{#1, #2}, #3} &, {{x1, y1, f1}, {x2, y2, f2}}, {1}]
```

For larger data they perform similarly, with Replace winning slightly:

```
In[53]:= data=(ToExpression/@{"x"<>#,"y"<>#,"f"<>#})&/@(ToString[#]&/@Range[1000000]);
Apply[{{#1,#2},#3}&,data,{1}]//RepeatedTiming//First
Replace[data,{x_,y_,f_}:>{{x,y},f},{1}]//RepeatedTiming//First
Out[54]= 0.825
Out[55]= 0.740
```

This is much better than the most naive approach:

```
In[57]:= ({{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, #[[3]]} & /@ data) // 
  RepeatedTiming // First

Out[57]= 1.859
```

The solution from @Oppenede is similar in timing to Apply

```
In[77]:= Transpose[{Drop[data, 0, -1], data[[All, -1]]}] // RepeatedTiming // First

Out[77]= 0.836
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{x1, y1, f1}, {x2, y2, f2}};

Transpose[{Drop[list, 0, -1], list[[All, -1]]}]
(* {{{x1, y1}, f1}, {{x2, y2}, f2}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a rule and replacement:

```
{{x1, y1, f1}, {x2, y2, f2}} /. {x_, y_, f_} -> {{x, y}, f}

(* {{{x1,y1},f1},{{x2,y2},f2}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you. This works well and I feel it could be useful as an example for other cases.

Comment: You’re welcome, Mikel. Using Replace with a rule based on a pattern, like this, is often less efficient than mapping an anonymous function. But I find it so clear and understandable that I often use it when execution time is not an issue.

Comment: It is better to use Replace with a level spec as this tests each expression at each level

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{x1, y1, f1}, {x2, y2, f2}};

{Most[#], Last[#]} & /@ list

(* {{{x1, y1}, f1}, {{x2, y2}, f2}} *)
```

Comment: This is a bit slower than the replace solutions and simliar to `{{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, #[[3]]} & /@ data`

Comment: @GenericAccountName Yes, it is. My personal preference is to avoid using `[[]]` as I find it quite visually jarring.

Comment: I agree, I prefer your syntax as well for this, the main point of my comment is this is a slower solution than others.